# Logging the output of VBoxHeadless

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I want to be able to launch a VM in headless mode and log the outputs of its tty to the command line.

Basically I have a situation where the VM will be launched remotely (hence the command line requirement), but every once and a while, the VM's bootup sequence freezes, and right now there's no way for me to debug why the VM is not booting up properly unless I go there manually and view it in a non-headless mode.

The VM itself does not have a GUI, it just boots into TTY mode.

So is there anyway I can get some debugging output from the TTY while it's headless?

One crazy idea would be using non-headless mode and taking screenshots of the window that opens, but there must be a better way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am trying to get some integration testing for bootstrapped virtualboxes up and running and ran into the exact same problem. After finding out that VRDP is a dead end, because RDP  cannot send text but only bitmaps, I remembered that some cloud providers require grub to output to ttyS0.

What is ttyS0 you ask? It's the serial console of course :-)
[Here's how to configure Debian to output to serial console](https://www.debian.org/releases/wheezy/amd64/ch05s03.html.en)
[VirtualBox allows you to redirect the serial port into either a file or a pipe](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Serial_redirect), meaning you should be able to get all the information you desire by simply reading the specified filepath.

Comment: Yup! Works like a charm. When using the socket option ("named pipe") I was able to print the console messages directly to my terminal using `socat` :-)
Here's a more programmatic way of accessing the output: http://goo.gl/ps6dDK

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following command to output a PNG file of the current screen, even in headless mode:

```
vboxmanage controlvm [vmname] screenshotpng screen.png
```

Comment: Nice. Quick and simple. But I would still prefer andsens's solution.